# How to compare row value with sum of group value from another pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have 2 dataframes which look like this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
                    'B': ['C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2'],
                    'Y': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                    'Z': [4, 5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5]})
Out[51]: 
   A   B  Y  Z
0  A  C1  0  4
1  B  C1  1  5
2  C  C1  1  2
3  D  C1  0  1
4  E  C2  1  2
5  F  C2  1  1
6  G  C2  0  3
7  H  C2  1  5

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'H'],
                    'B': ['C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2'],
                    'V': [2, 3, 1, 4, 2]})
Out[52]: 
   A   B  V
0  A  C1  2
1  B  C1  3
2  E  C2  1
3  F  C2  4
4  H  C2  2
```

I would like to select all rows in df1 where Y==1 and Z.cumsum() <= V.sum() of the respective group value in df2. group is column B.

THIS IS MY DESIRED OUTPUT

```
   A   B  Y  Z
1  B  C1  1  5
4  E  C2  1  2
5  F  C2  1  1
```

LOGIC

```
df2.groupby('B')['V'].sum()
Out[57]: 
B
C1    5
C2    7
Name: V, dtype: int64
```

so the following should hold TRUE

for rows in group C1: df1.loc[(df1.Y==1)].groupby('B')['Z'].cumsum() should be <=5

for rows in group C2: df1.loc[(df1.Y==1)].groupby('B')['Z'].cumsum() should be <=7

how can I make this selection in 1 line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use use `map` on df1.B with the result from df2. Note that I use `where` and not `loc` that just replace by nan the values in Z where it is not Y==1

```
print(df1[df1['Z'].where(df1['Y']==1).groupby(df1['B']).cumsum()
          <=df1['B'].map(df2.groupby('B')['V'].sum())])
   A   B  Y  Z
1  B  C1  1  5
4  E  C2  1  2
5  F  C2  1  1
```